# Inheritance Design

Tags: oop, inheritance

Right now, I have the following design:

```
                      Item
            |------------------------|
       ImageUploader                 |
     |--------------|                |
     |              |                |
AvatarUploader   FaviconUploader   NameChanger
```

These classes are various items that users can purchase and use.

However, I'm adding a new class `IconUploader`. Unlike the other classes, this is not an item that can be used, but an administrative panel. `ImageUploader` contains certain security checks to make sure only safe files are uploaded, and `IconUploader` needs these precautions as well.

However, I'm not sure what to do. Ideally, I'd make `ImageUploader` an interface, but you can't have actual code in interfaces, so I can't do that. I could move `ImageUploader` out of the `Item` class hierarchy and make its functions static, but that doesn't feel right to me. Is it? And if it isn't, what is the best way to restructure this?

*N.B.: I'm using PHP, if that affects anything.*

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have a `GenericUploader`, and then each type of uploader can specify a list of valid files, then the `GenericUploader` will ensure those requirements are met (along with anything else you might wish it do to).

Comment: Right, but where do I put this class? If I keep it in the item hierarchy, that makes ImageUploader an item, even though it isn't. If I move it outside of the item hierarchy, since objects can only extend one class, AvatarUploader can't be a child of both that and Item, unless I make it an interface, but then it can't contain any code.

Comment: It goes above `ImageUploader`. Then, `IconUploader` can be at the same level as `ImageUploader`. (so, you move the security checks up, and they both inherit from it).

Comment: I think I've miscommunicated. IconUploader uploads images, but it isn't an item, unlike the others.

Comment: @wai: Ah. I guess I'm a bit confused what an `Item` is then. Perhaps you need to go a route of having a "ValidationEngine" type object, which all relevant parties have access to, and centralise the validation that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `ImageUploaderBase` class which is abstract and have the common functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the security checking and common upload functionality for the uploaders into a separate **Uploader** class, and make ImageUploader use this Uploader class (so all derived classes like Avatar/FaviconUploader would use it as well).

Then you could make IconUploader use Uploader (without it being derived from Item).

Then you can make ImageUploader and IconUploader implement an **IUploader** interface, and have all calls to the interface forwarded to the Uploader class to implement.